# Fedex India configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, fedex

Is FedEx extension in build in Magento configurable for shipping within India.
I have tried configuring the same with all the required details from FedEx developer section but it fails to calculate the shipping cost and returns that shipping is not configured.

Comment: debug and update your request and response here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the India to India domestic shipping to work you need to add in a PurposeOfShipment type to the request. This line is not standard in Magento's code for Fedex shipping. That line will be added into CustomsClearanceDetail header as a child under CommercialInvoice then a line under that is Purposewhich can have any value that PurposeOfShipment has.

Here is an example of the request I used that returned proper shipping estimates for India to India shipping.

```
'CustomsClearanceDetail' => array(
     'CommercialInvoice' => array(
       'Purpose' => "SOLD"
    )
),
```

Also Rates for some reason won't work with test credentials,whereas for production they are working fine!